# How to remain same pagination page on table after action

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, pagination, datatables

i have created a table (using datatables) and in the table a few actions. in the table i have a button to do a function "delete", also using datatables i get pagination.. So for example i am at page 5, and i want to delete a row when i click delete it refreshes the page and goes back to page no 1. How can i make it remain at page 5 after the action delete? Below are my table and controller function

viewStatistics.blade:

```html
<table class="table table-hover demo-table-search table-responsive-block alt-table" id="tableWithSearch">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center" style="width:80px;">ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Date</th>
      <th class="text-center">Question <br> Asked</th>
      <th class="text-center">Low <br> Confidence</th>
      <th class="text-center">No <br> Answer</th>
      <th class="text-center">Missing <br> Intent</th>
      <th class="text-center">Webhook <br> Fail</th>
      <th class="text-center">Status</th>
      <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($data as $sessionID => $value)
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['identifier']}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{date("d M", strtotime($value['dateAccess']))}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['total']}}</td> <!-- question asked -->
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['low confidence']}}</td> <!-- low confidence -->
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['no answer']}}</td> <!-- no answer -->
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['missing intent']}}</td> <!-- missing intent -->
        <td class="text-center">{{$value['webhook fail']}}</td> <!-- webhook fail -->
        <td class="text-center" style="{{$value['status'] == 'Reviewed' ? 'color:green' : 'color:red'}}">
          {{$value['status']}}
          @if($value['status'] == 'Pending')
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="check" value="{{$sessionID}}">
          @endif
        </td> <!-- status -->
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-black dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@viewStatisticsLog', [$companyID, $sessionID, $value['status'], $value['identifier']])}}" class="btn btn-link">View</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@deleteStatistics', [$companyID, $sessionID])}}" class="btn btn-link" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure that you want to delete this chat logs?')">Delete</a>
              </li>
              @if($value['status'] == 'Pending')
              <li>
                <a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@updateStatisticsStatus', [$companyID, $sessionID])}}" class="btn btn-link">Mark as Done</a>
              </li>
              @endif
            </ul>
          </div>
        </td> <!-- action -->
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```html
public function deleteStatistics($companyID, $sessionID)
{
  DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $sessionID)->delete();
  return redirect(action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@viewStatistics', compact('companyID')))->with('notification',[
    'status' => 'success',
    'title' => 'Statistics Deleted',
    'message' => 'The Statistics have been deleted.'
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option named **stateSave** in jquery datatables. Please check the code below:

```
$('#example').dataTable({ stateSave: true });
```

Comment: Hi, because im doing this in laravel, should i use this code in the blade file?

Comment: Yes, you can add it.

Comment: thank you it worked. also do you know if the datatables i can add a code which can skip pages like >skip 5,  or >skip 10?

Comment: As of now, there is no skip page option available in datatables I guess.