# How Can I Make the DataTable Remember the Search and Pagination State After Deleting a Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want the datatable remember the search filter and pagination when deleting a row. I wrote a function that re-initializes the datatable after the data is deleted at the server-side, but the "state" is gone.

A partial view containing the table is returned from the server.

I guess there's something that remembers the state, but I could not find it.

Here's the code:

```
if ($('#tblAllFiles')) {
            var oTableAllFiles = $('#tblAllFiles').dataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "bDestroy": true,  
                "columns": [
                    // Company File Number column
                    { "searchable": true },
                    { "searchable": false },
                    // Client Name column
                    { "searchable": true },
                    // File Number column
                    { "searchable": true },
                    // Company column
                    { "searchable": true },
                    { "searchable": false },
                    // File Status column
                    { "searchable": true },
                    { "searchable": false }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "There are no files."
                },
                //"initComplete": dataTableInitCompleteFunction()
                "initComplete": function () {
                    console.log("initComplete");
                    var columnCompany = this.api().columns([4]);
                    var selectCompany = $("#selectCompany");
                    selectCompany.empty();
                    selectCompany.append('<option value="Company">Company</option>');
                    columnCompany.every(function () {
                        this.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            selectCompany.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    });
                    selectCompany.on("change", function () {
                        var selectedCompany = $(this).val();
                        columnCompany
                            .search(selectedCompany ? '^' + selectedCompany + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                    var columnFileStatus = this.api().columns([6]);
                    var selectFileStatus = $("#selectFileStatus");
                    selectFileStatus.empty();
                    selectFileStatus.append('<option value="File Status">File Status</option>');
                    columnFileStatus.every(function () {
                        this.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            selectFileStatus.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    });
                    selectFileStatus.on("change", function () {
                        var selectedFileStatus = $(this).val();
                        console.log(selectedFileStatus);
                        columnFileStatus
                            .search(selectedFileStatus ? '^' + selectedFileStatus + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });
                 }
            });
            //$("#tblAllFiles_filter").css("display", "none");
        }
    });

    function fileDeleteCallback(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.isFileDeleted) {
            alert("An error occured. The file was NOT deleted.");
        }
        else {
            $("#divFilesSearchResult").html(result);              
            dataTableInitCompleteFunction();
        }              
    }       

    function dataTableInitCompleteFunction() {
        console.log("initComplete");
        var dt = $('#tblAllFiles').dataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "columns": [
                // Company File Number column
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": false },
                // Client Name column
                { "searchable": true },
                // File Number column
                { "searchable": true },
                // Company column
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": false },
                // File Status column
                { "searchable": true },
                { "searchable": false }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "There are no files."
            }
        });
        var api = dt.dataTable().api();
        var columnCompany = api.columns([4]);
        var selectCompany = $("#selectCompany");
        selectCompany.empty();
        selectCompany.append('<option value="Company">Company</option>');
        columnCompany.every(function () {
            this.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                selectCompany.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });
        });
        selectCompany.on("change", function () {
            var selectedCompany = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
                columnCompany
                    .search(selectedCompany ? '^' + selectedCompany + '$' : '', true, false)
                    .draw();
            }
            else {
                columnCompany
                    .search('', true, false)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
        var columnFileStatus = api.columns([6]);
        var selectFileStatus = $("#selectFileStatus");
        selectFileStatus.empty();
        selectFileStatus.append('<option value="File Status">File Status</option>');

        columnFileStatus.every(function () {
            this.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                selectFileStatus.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });
        });
        selectFileStatus.on("change", function () {
            var selectedFileStatus = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
                columnFileStatus
                    .search(selectedFileStatus ? '^' + selectedFileStatus + '$' : '', true, false)
                    .draw();
            }
            else {
                columnFileStatus
                    .search('', true, false)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you can use `draw(false)`, see de [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

Comment: Please refer the answer I posted for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408222/how-to-remain-same-pagination-page-on-table-after-action/47413160#47413160. Here **stateSave** option will help you to retrieve the pagination and filter information.